# How to pass dynamic data to a single bootstrap-vue modal instance and reuse it multiple times inside a loop?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to pass data to a single modal instance and reuse it multiple times inside a loop. It is working but whenever I'm clicking over an image, I'm getting an error - `You may have an infinite update loop in a component render function.`

This is the html where I'm looping over an array of images and passing it to a modal instance.

```
<li v-for="(source, i) in sources()" :key="i+'K'">
    <span v-b-modal.fancybox @click="fancyBox(source)">
        <p>click me</p>
    </span>
</li>
```

This is the html for bootstrap-vue modal -

```
<b-modal
  id="fancybox"
  :modal-class="myclass"
  hide-footer
  centered
>
  <img class="fancybox" :src="resource">
</b-modal>
```

Following is the vue js code -

```
export default {
  data: () => ({
    myclass: ['myclass'],
    srcItems: [],
    resource: ''
  }),

  methods: {
    sources () {
      this.srcItems = [
        'https://picsum.photos/id/0/5616/3744',
        'https://picsum.photos/id/1/5616/3744',
        'https://picsum.photos/id/10/2500/1667',
        'https://picsum.photos/id/100/2500/1656',
        'https://picsum.photos/id/1000/5626/3635'
      ]
      return this.srcItems
    },
    fancyBox (source) {
      this.resource = source
    }
  }
}
```

I couldn't able to figure out what is wrong here! Please help me. Thank you for your time.

Comment: I would try to keep one single modal, but assigning the data dynamically each time the modal is opened.

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: @germanio How can I do that please help me on this ?

Answer (score -2):

Hope this will help you to get started

```
**[LIVE DEMO](https://codepen.io/boussadjra/pen/xxERwZm)**
```